# How to extract XML attributes when unnesting XML that has been converted to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
xml_reprex <- '<Athletes>
  <Athlete>
    <AthleteIdentifier Id="157" />
      <TotalGames>354</TotalGames>
        <GamesByType>
          <Games Type="Regular">301</Games>
          <Games Type="Finals">53</Games>
        </GamesByType>
  </Athlete>
  <Athlete>
    <AthleteIdentifier Id="223" />
      <TotalGames>154</TotalGames>
        <GamesByType>
          <Games Type="Regular">142</Games>
          <Games Type="Finals">12</Games>
        </GamesByType>
  </Athlete>
</Athletes>'
```

I would like to turn this into a tidy data frame with columns `AthleteIdentifier`, `TotalGames`, `GameType` and `Games`.

Here is my current attempt:

```
df <- read_xml(xml_reprex) 

as_tibble(as_list(df)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(Athletes, names_repair = "universal") %>% 
  unnest(TotalGames) %>% 
  unnest(TotalGames) %>% 
  unnest(GamesByType) %>% 
  unnest(GamesByType) %>% 
  unnest(GamesByType)
```

However, I lose the `AthleteIdentifier` values as they are listed as an attribute, similarly I lose the `Games` type as it is an attribute as well.

Is this because I have converted it to a tibble and therefore I lose all those attributes? Is there a way I can retain that information in the conversion to a tibble for for manipulation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. It relies mostly on `tidyr`'s function `extract`, which uses regular expression to describe the string in toto and separate out strings to be extracted with capturing groups in parentheses:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(xml_reprex) %>%
  mutate(xml_reprex = gsub("</?Athletes>|\n\\s+", "", xml_reprex)) %>%
  separate_rows(xml_reprex, sep = "(?<!^)<Athlete>") %>%
  extract(xml_reprex,
          into = c("AthleteIdentifier", "TotalGames", "GameType_Regular", "GameType_Finals"),
          regex = 'AthleteIdentifier Id="(\\d+)".*TotalGames>(\\d+)<.*Games Type="Regular">(\\d+).*Games Type="Finals">(\\d+)')
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  AthleteIdentifier TotalGames GameType_Regular GameType_Finals
  <chr>             <chr>      <chr>            <chr>          
1 157               354        301              53             
2 223               154        142              12
```